# How do I make a code wait for an object before proceeding with a println in Java?

Tags: java, encryption

I have a code which encrypts to Aes-128 by taking a scanner method and encrypting it. When the program is run, the encryption terminates without waiting for a response. I tried

```
    try {

         Thread.sleep(10000);

    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {

         Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
```

but if I typed something really long it would encrypt

> java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match valid=false][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decimal separator=.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\Q�\E][infinity string=\Q∞\E]

without waiting for a response from the scanner.

Here is the code (It's a modified code from: http://aesencryption.net/ ):

```
    package package1;

    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.security.MessageDigest;
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
    import java.util.*;
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
    import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

    public class AesOne{


    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;
    private static byte[] key;


    private static String decryptedString;
    private static String encryptedString;

public static void setKey(String myKey){


    MessageDigest sha = null;
    try {
        key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
        System.out.println(key.length);
        sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        key = sha.digest(key);
        key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
        System.out.println(key.length);
        System.out.println(new String(key,"UTF-8"));
        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");


    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

public static String getDecryptedString() {
    return decryptedString;
}
public static void setDecryptedString(String decryptedString) {
    AesOne.decryptedString = decryptedString;
}
public static String getEncryptedString() {
    return encryptedString;
}
public static void setEncryptedString(String encryptedString) {
    AesOne.encryptedString = encryptedString;
}
public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt)
{
    try
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);


        setEncryptedString(Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"))));

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        System.out.println("Error while encrypting: "+e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt)
{
    try
    {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        setDecryptedString(new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt))));

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        System.out.println("Error while decrypting: "+e.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
public static void main(String args[])
{



            System.out.println("What would you like to encrypt?");

            Scanner encrypt = new Scanner(System.in);
            String toEncrypt = encrypt.toString();

            final String strToEncrypt = toEncrypt;
            final String strPssword = "encryptor key";
            AesOne.setKey(strPssword);

            AesOne.encrypt(strToEncrypt.trim());

            System.out.println("String to Encrypt: " + strToEncrypt); 
            System.out.println("Encrypted: " + AesOne.getEncryptedString());

            final String strToDecrypt =  AesOne.getEncryptedString();
            AesOne.decrypt(strToDecrypt.trim());

            System.out.println("String To Decrypt : " + strToDecrypt);
            System.out.println("Decrypted : " + AesOne.getDecryptedString());

}

}
```

(I think the indenting may be weird on here)

Comment: Did the code work without you modifying it? If so, maybe try to backtrack your error?

Comment: Is there any error? what do you mean by `the encryption terminates without waiting for a response`? what if you place `System.out.flush()` at the end of main?

Comment: You have to use "String toEncrypt = encrypt.next();" instead of "String toEncrypt = encrypt.toString();". Then the Scanner will wait until Enter has been pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use

```
String toEncrypt = encrypt.next();
```

instead of

```
String toEncrypt = encrypt.toString();
```

Then the Scanner will wait until Enter has been pressed.

.toString() immediately stops the waiting process and delivers a String-representation of the current Scanner's content.

Comment: ah... I assumed he was passing in the toString of the object as a way to test the encryption.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried the code and it is working fine.... if you are kicking this off from a unit test (i.e., within JUnit) then the Unit Test thread may be ending before the response comes back.  I have had this problem for long(er) running tasks.  **If it is in a unit test**, you could try adding an AfterClass call like this one to force the unit test to wait...

```
    @AfterClass
    public static void afterClass() {

        // the threads to finish before we terminate JUNIT
        Thread sleepyThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                // wait for a bit 
                try {
                    this.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        // start the sleepy thread
        try {
            sleepyThread.start();
            sleepyThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    System.err.println("Done running tests");

    }
```